# IE8 CSS background colour not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, web

I am making a fictitious website to boost up my portfolio. The website in questions address is http://www.jn-design.co.uk/PJ.

The problem is that within IE 8 , the header and footer background colour does not show at all.Please view it in a more recent browser and you will see the problem!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you rewrite / edit your question so it doesn't depend on the external link, that way if you fix the linked site this question may still be useful to future visitors. In other words: focus down on the problematic lines of code and include them in your question.

Comment: I could not figure out the exact area of the code though for my problem? I wasnt going to paste in my whole css?

Comment: It's typically preferred [questions contain some source code](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), and it's more or less required that your question is [relevant to others besides yourself (see "too localized")](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) (which is quite impossible if the only real info is found behind a link to your own site). In addition [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkrot) or you fixing your site will make the question obsolete soon enough.

Comment: If you have trouble debugging the code causing your problems, always remember your last resort: eliminating 50% of your code one step at a time, trimming down the code until you found the line(s) responsible.

Answer (score 3):

IE8 doesn't know the `<header>` and `<footer>` elements; they're HTML5. There are ways around this like http://modernizr.com/, https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv, or a JavaScript chunk like:

```
<script>
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

Comment: Didnt even think of that! Many Thanks... After seeing this I found this solution: `<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`

Comment: Think I just found what you are talking about? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

the background is showing correctrly try to clear the cache